# Range Restrictions in PGF/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am currently trying to put multiple graphs in one `\tikzpicture` but when I try and put in the tangent function, due to its undefined nature  at pi/2 and my domain being defined as `-pi:pi` my LaTeX compiler keeps freaking out.  Here's the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:pi]
    \draw[very thin, color=gray] (-pi,-1) grid (pi,1);

    \draw[->] (-7.0,0) -- (7.0,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};

    \draw[color=red]    plot(\x,{sin(\x r)}) node[right] {$f(x) = \sin(x)$};
    \draw[color=blue]   plot(\x,{cos(\x r)}) node[right] {$f(x) = \cos(x)$};
    \draw[color=orange] plot(\x,{tan(\x r)}) node[right] {$f(x) = \tan(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My big question is how can I put range restrictions on this graph in order to graph the tangent function of is there some other library I should use for this?

Comment: Have you considered using pgfplots instead. It can handle such things (mostly)

Comment: I am looking into that currently.  Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Welcome! Please always post complete, compilable code which reproduces the error or problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `pgfplots` it is a little more cumbersome. The upper and lower borders from the grid are 1 and -1, thus the angles needs to be calculated. Then the visible, allowed parts of the tan function can be displayed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-pi:pi]
  \draw[very thin, color=gray] (-pi,-1) grid (pi,1);

  \draw[->] (-4,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};

  \draw[color=red]    plot(\x,{sin(\x r)})
    node[above right] {$f(x) = \sin(x)$};
  \draw[color=blue]   plot(\x,{cos(\x r)})
    node[right] {$f(x) = \cos(x)$};
  \draw[color=orange]
    plot[domain=-pi:-.75*pi] (\x, {tan(\x r)})
    plot[domain=-.25*pi:.25*pi] (\x, {tan(\x r)})
    plot[domain=.75*pi:pi](\x,{tan(\x r)})
    node[below right] {$f(x) = \tan(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't let us know if you have found a solution so far, here one possibility ...

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % set the labels at the axes
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$f(x)$,
            % set the domain where the values of the functions should be calculated for
            domain=0:pi,
            % draw the lines "smooth"
            smooth,
            % set limits of the axis
            xmin=0,
            xmax=pi,
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=2,
            % to avoid PGF Math Errors (while calculating the tangent values)
            % restrict the y domain
            % for that the limits should be a bit larger than the axis limits
            % (compare with the result if the limits are equal)
            restrict y to domain=-5:5,
        ]
            \addplot [red]      function {sin(x)};
            \addplot [blue]     function {cos(x)};
            \addplot [orange]   function {tan(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `tan` function (named `mytan` in the example) in a way to make it defined anywhere.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{
  function mytan(\x) {
    if  abs(cos(\x)) < .001 then {
      return 100;
    } else {
      return tan(\x);
    };
  };
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-pi:pi, samples=100]
      \draw[very thin, color=gray] (-pi,-1) grid (pi,1);
      \clip  (-pi,-2) rectangle (2*pi,2);

      \draw[->] (-7.0,0) -- (7.0,0) node[right] {$x$};
      \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};

      \draw[color=red]    plot(\x,{sin(\x r)}) node[above right] {$f(x) = \sin(x)$};
      \draw[color=blue]   plot(\x,{cos(\x r)}) node[right] {$f(x) = \cos(x)$};
      \draw[color=orange] plot(\x,{mytan(\x r)}) node[below right] {$f(x) = \tan(x)$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]